# JLabel não recebe texto novo

Tags: java

Esse código era para ser quando ele clicasse no botão o mesmo ficasse invisível e o `lblVira` se tornasse um número entre 0 e 10, não dá nenhuma mensagem de erro e compila só que o `lblVira` não "pega" o novo texto (sou novo em java).

```
private void btnstartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    btnstart.setVisible(false);
    Random random = new Random();
        int array[] = new int[1]; 

        for (int i=1; i<array.length; i++) {
             array[i] = random.nextInt(10); 
            lblVira.setText(Integer.toString(array[i]));
        }    }
```

Comment: Você criou um vetor de 1 posição, depois fez um `for` que executa começando em 1 e vai enquanto 1 < 1, ou seja, nunca. O `for` não deveria começar em 0? E por quê um array de 1 posição? Apenas `int` não seria suficiente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void btnstartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    btnstart.setVisible(false);
    Random random = new Random();
        int array[] = new int[1]; 

        for (int i=1; i<array.length; i++) {
             array[i] = random.nextInt(10); 
            lblVira.setText(Integer.toString(array[i]));
        }    }
```

Olhe esse `for`. Ele roda enquanto `i<1`. Ocorre que uma vez que ele começa com `i=1`, então a condição do `for` já começa falsa e ele não vai fazer nada.

Acho que você queria `i=0` ao invés de `i=1`.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que você quer algo assim:

```
private void btnstartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    btnstart.setVisible(false);
    Random random = new Random();
    int numeroAleatorio = random.nextInt(10); 
    lblVira.setText(Integer.toString(numeroAleatorio));
}
```

Não tem necessidade de criar um `ArrayList`

Comment: na verdade era bem isso que eu queria mesmo, mas como estou começando a programar agora array foi a primeira coisa que me veio na cabeça de qualquer forma, obrigado

Comment: sugiro que comece com javascript, é uma linguagem simples e muito usada